best way to generate new program_id?
After calling anchor init anchor-counter and anchor build, I get a new program_id, so I call anchor keys sync to sync the anchor.toml file and declare_id!
But what if I already deployed the contract to this program_id and I make changes and now want to deploy to a different program_id? How do I create a randomly generated program_id? I don't think it is best to do this:
solana-keygen new -o target/deploy/pogo-keypair.json

because this will also generate a private key (which I don't think we want for programs?)

a private key is required the first time you deploy a program, theres nothing wrong with generating a new one. a program id is just the pubkey/address that corresponds to that private key
a program owned by BPFLoaderUpgradeable (the standard loader) has two important accounts: the program account, and the programdata account. the program account is at the address of the program id and only contains the address of the programdata account. the programdata account contains the last update slot, upgrade authority if there is one, and the program bytecode. the reason for this is because the program account can never be changed after deployment, so the data that can change is in programdata
the program account is a normal account created using system_instruction::create_account, so it needs to sign with its private key when its created. after the program is deployed, all program updates happen with the upgrade authority, and the keypair for the program account becomes useless and can safely be deleted
